# agGridReact focusing cellRendererComponent elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am implementing keyboard navigation functionality on agGridReact,

I am using cellRendererFramework property of colDef to render bespoke react component as below

```
const columnDefs = [{ headerName: 'Athlete', field: 'athlete', cellRendererFramework: InputRenderer }, ...]
```

component looks something like below, each columns have their own renderer component

```
class InputRenderer extends React.Component { 
render() { 
<input value={this.props.value} />
}
}

Grid looks like 
<AgGridReact> 
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  singleClickEdit={true}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}
suppressCellSelection={true}
</AgGridReact>
```

I need to navigate from only to these tabable elements, i.e. from input displaying value of column 1 when I press tab it should focus to input field of cellRendererComponent of column 1, bit lost here. 
There are examples on ag-grid site (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/) but they are not using custom react component, it navigates on their example but uses built in editor fields, columns with editable property set to true, I instead have custom react components.

below is what out put I am getting, focus is neither on button nor on input [image], What I am looking for is when I tab focus should be on button of next column, pressing tab on that button should move focus to input field next to it and so on.

Answer (score 0):

add a componentdidmount() and in there add an explicit focus using a ref. That worked for me